# File descriptor from `signalfd(2)` is never ready to read

Tags: linux, signals, process-management

I have a fairly big application under care. As part of its job it spawns some child processes and needs to monitor their state (running, crashed).

Child process deaths were detected by setting signal handler for `SIGCHLD` using `signal(2)`. Some time ago I migrated it to `signalfd(2)`. What I did was simple:

1. removed the signal handler for `SIGCHLD`
2. blocked `SIGCHLD` and created a `signalfd(2)` to capture `SIGCHLD`

My problem is that the file descriptor I created does not seem to capture `SIGCHLD`. However, if I ignore the return value of `read(2)` call on that descriptor and call `waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)` I *can* obtain the information about exited child processes. So it looks like the notification is delivered but my `signalfd(2)` descriptor just ignores it.

I made sure to have exactly one place in the program where `read(2)` is called on the `signalfd(2)` descriptor, exactly one place where `waitpid(2)` is called, and exactly one place were the signal handling is set up.

The setup code looks like this:

```
sigset_t mask;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);

sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, nullptr);

int signal_fd = signalfd(-1, &mask, SFD_NONBLOCK | SFD_CLOEXEC);
if (signal_fd == -1) {
    /* log failure and exit */
} else {
    /* log success */
}
```

The reading code looks like this:

```
signalfd_siginfo info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));

if (read(signal_fd, &info, sizeof(info)) == -1) {
    /*
     * Log failure and return.
     * The file descriptor *always* returns EAGAIN, even in
     * presence of dead child processes.
     */
    return;
}

if (info.ssi_signo == SIGCHLD) {
    int status = 0;
    int child = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);

    /*
     * Process result of waitpid(2). The call is successful even if
     * the read of signalfd above returned an error.
     */
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** The problem is that `read(2)` fails with `EAGAIN` even if there are dead child processes ready to be `waitpid(2)`-ed, which means that a `SIGCHLD` must have been delivered to my master process. I know that `read(2)` may return `EAGAIN` for non-blocking file descriptors and the code accounts for that.

Comment: Non-blocking IO is a pain. It looks like a good idea, until you try it. Instead use blocking, and learn how to do event driven with `select` or `poll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When migrating from signal handling based on `signal(2)` or `sigaction(2)` to `signalfd(2)` you change the way you receive signals. The old way leaves the signals unblocked, the new one needs them blocked.

If you have some regions of code in which you do not want to be disturbed by signals you need to block them:

```
sigset_t mask;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask, SIGFOO);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, nullptr);

{
    /* not-to-be-disturbed code here */
}
```

This requires that you later *unblock* them, because otherwise `signal(2)` or `sigaction(2)` will not be able to pick them up.

```
{
    /* not-to-be-disturbed code here */
}

pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, nullptr);
```

However, for `signalfd(2)` the signals must stay blocked. If you have a long neglected code path that you rarely look at and it follows the old way ie, blocks and unblocks some signals, it may trash your signal-reading file descriptor you got from `signalfd(2)`.

**TL;DR** Vet your code for any calls to `signal(2)`, `sigaction(2)`, `pthread_sigmask(2)` etc. when migrating to `signalfd(2)` to check if you did not forget about some codepath that messes with the signal mask.

(Two and a half years later may be a bit late, but maybe the answer will help someone.)

Comment: It'd help to if the code originally put the temporary blocking and unblocking in separate functions, then it'd be enough to just quench them. Or if those functions supported nested blocking (using a counter, probably), then the main program could just ask for all signals blocked in the start, and the functions would never unblock them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `read(2)` returns `EAGAIN` because you opened the file in non-blocking mode with `signalfd(..., SFD_NONBLOCK | ...)` (`SFD_NONBLOCK` is the same as `O_NONBLOCK`).

Don't open or set file descriptors to non-blocking mode if you want to do blocking reads on them.

Comment: The fact that `read(2)` returns `EAGAIN` is actually what I wanted - if I get this errno I just skip further processing. The problem is that `EAGAIN` is returned even if there *are* child processes waiting to be `waitpid(2)`-ed.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You want do a blocking read() -- you turn off O_NONBLOCK. If you turn O_NONBLOCK on -- you should use poll(), select(), epoll(), etc. It's as simple as that.

Comment: OK, I'll try that. But then I'm curious - is there a difference between calling `read()` and checking for `EAGAIN`, and using `select()` to detect readiness? Except for "that's how you ought to do it", of course.

Comment: You claim that if the waipid() is able to reap a child, then the SIGCHLD should've been already delivered. I don't see any base for that, and I don't see why the signalfd would go out of its way to guarantee that.

Comment: There must be a use for non-blocking, and I would assume that it works. I don't like it because it makes your code spin. And because of that one time, where I had to get someone else's code to work, and ended up converting it to blocking, as I could not get non-blocking to work. But surely it must be usable.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I also assumed it would work, as it works for me in another program. I agree with you that blocking code is easier to understand, but in this case I cannot afford to block. I'll probably turn to select() and friends if nothing else helps.

Comment: @Mael your code may have of course other problems. If you posted a complete example, you may get a better answer ;-)

Comment: Yes give an example of the simplest code that works, but exhibits the problem. ( Nearly every time I do this, I find the problem my self). And what can you not afford about blocking?

Comment: @mosvy You're right - I couldn't find any source stating that `SIGCHLD` is guaranteed to be delivered before `waitpid(2)` is allowed to notice a change in child's status, and when I think about it there is no reason why it shouldn't be (and `signalfd(2)` is tied to signals so that would explain its non-readiness).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I need to make the program's responses as fast as possible to maintain some soft deadlines. I use this check-for-`EAGAIN` in several places, but as you say - getting it to work can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: You should check your assumptions about performance. Always test your assumptions, when optimising code.